# sqlite select query with decimal/float comparison doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, decimal

I need to perform decimal comparison operations using a simple select, for example:

select * from table_a where time > 0.0004

id    time

---

0      0.000502
1      0.000745
2      0.000725
4      0.000197
5      0.000176
6      0.000833
7      0.000269
8      0.000307
9      0.000302

The result contains values that do satisfy the comparison. In a few words, "time > 0.0004" always evaluates to true, and "time < 0.0004" always evaluates to false.

I have tried casting and changing the type of the time column from decimal to float without success.

If I use a subquery, it performs the query correctly:

select * from table_a where time > (select time from table_a where id=8);

id    time

---

0      0.000502
1      0.000745
2      0.000725
6      0.000833

Table create:

CREATE TABLE "table_a" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "time" decimal NOT NULL);

Comment: What does `SELECT id, time, typeof(time) FROM table_a` return?

Comment: The typeof(time) returns "text" for all rows. I used the ".import" command to load the table, it seems this is the problem. If I insert records using "INSERT" the type of the values is "real" instead of "text".

Comment: thanks for posting your detailed explanation of how the data got inserted as text.  SQLite is a little tricky sometimes if you don't watch out for those datatype mishaps.  Personally all our schemas have `check` constraints on the columns to enforce specific data types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite has an unorthodox dynamic-typing system where the type of a column doesn't determine the type of the actual data in the column, it merely encourages SQLite to convert data to a particular type if that happens to be possible.

When trying to compare a string and a number, if the string isn't a well-formed number then it's considered greater than the number.

So an obvious guess is that for some reason these time values aren't actually numbers but strings. That's puzzling for two reasons. (1) Since the `time` column has type `decimal`, it should have "numeric" affinity, which should get anything stored in it that looks like a number converted to be a number. (2) Even if the values were stored as strings, they should still have been converted to numbers for comparing against 0.0004.

Why might they not have been converted? Possibility #1: maybe they contain extra spaces or something of the sort. Possibility #2: maybe your locale wants to use something other than `.` as the decimal point. (There may well be other possibilities that I haven't thought of.)

If you insert a record into the table that actually contains a number -- `insert into table_a (id,time) values (999,0.0001)` or something of the sort -- does that record get included in your selection?

Comment: The INSERT of 0.0001 does get included in the selection. See my answer for Samuel Neff.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to all your suggestions, I have found the root of the problem:

**The "time" column values were being handled as "text". Why?**

I was importing data to the table using ".import" and my CSV file contained spaces around the decimal values. Somehow, SQLite's import command allows the inserts to happen even if the types do not match. After I removed the spaces from the CSV file, the data is inserted as "real", which allows for the number comparisons to happen correctly. HOWEVER, it does not explain why the data in the "decimal" column is of type "real" and not "decimal" or "numeric" as explained in their docs: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

```
select id, time, typeof(time) from table_a;
id    time           type
----  -------------  ----
0      0.000502      text
1      0.000745      text
2      0.000725      text
4      0.000197      text
5      0.000176      text
6      0.000833      text
7      0.000269      text
8      0.000307      text
9      0.000302      text

select id, time, typeof(time) from table_b;
id    time           type
----  -------------  ----
0     0.000502       real
1     0.000745       real
2     0.000725       real
4     0.000197       real
5     0.000176       real
6     0.000833       real
7     0.000269       real
8     0.000307       real
9     0.000302       real
```

Comment: Aha, spaces. Told ya. :-) As for the type: "decimal" and "numeric" are column types, but not data types, in SQLite. They tell SQLite what conversions to try on data in the column, but they aren't themselves possible types for the data. Take another look at that page you linked to.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but i want to give another answer.

Because SQLite tends to see everything as text, the following happens:

If you query `... where a < 1000` it will never find anything if a is treated as text

if you query  `... where a < '1000'` it will compare the one-thousand as some sort of text and has issues if the numbers have different character lenght. 1000 is 4 chars and 100 is 3 etc

But there is the CAST expression http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr

so `... where cast(a as Integer) < 1000` will result in what you want (can ofc be done with REAL for floats)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the behavior you see.  I get the right results even if I

- define the time column as varchar,
- insert value within single quotes,
- insert value within double quotes,
- define the time column as decimal and
  insert text literals first ('test text')

But, like Samuel Neff, I'd still like to see the result of `SELECT id, time, typeof(time) FROM table_a;` in your database. You know what else might be interesting? The result of

```
select * from table_a order by time;
```

These results are from version 3.7.4, which might not be the current version.

```
sqlite> .dump table_a
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "table_a" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "time" decimal NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO "table_a" VALUES(1,0.4);
INSERT INTO "table_a" VALUES(2,0.6);
INSERT INTO "table_a" VALUES(3,0.0005);
INSERT INTO "table_a" VALUES(4,0.0006);
INSERT INTO "table_a" VALUES(5,0.0004);
COMMIT;

sqlite> select * from table_a where time < 0.0005;
5|0.0004

sqlite> SELECT id, time, typeof(time) FROM table_a;
1|0.4|real
2|0.6|real
3|0.0005|real
4|0.0006|real
5|0.0004|real
```

Comment: The "ORDER BY time" does return an ordered result. However, I ran your transaction and the selection was working fine. I think the problem is that I used ".import" to load the table. I will do more testing and post my results.

Comment: I was sure it would be ordered. I wasn't sure it would be *numerically* ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it wasn't your case, but keep in mind that sometimes some administration tools (like [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) or [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/)) may show you real values as equal, although they are not. Here's an example:

[image: Number Comparison]

The difference is minor, but is probably enough to give you a hard headache.